# jquery add variable to $.get url parameter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, jquery-get

I´ve been banging my head against the $.get-function of jquery.

I´m trying to do something like this:

```
$("#button").click(function(){

var value=$("#textfield").val();

alert(value);

$.get('lookup.php?s=<?php echo $id?>&q=+ value',function(data) {

$(#result).html(data);
```

This should query lookup.php with GET-parameters:

$id (PHP-variable) 
&
value (jquery/Javascript-variable)

The thing is, that the $id is being filled in correctly, but the "value" of the previous
jquery/javascript assignment is not.

Playing with the data:-parameters did not help at all.

Is there a way I can append a jquery-variable from a textfield input to the query string ?

I need to call $.get with those 2 parameters and I cannot find a way in my head to do it
otherwise :-).

Hope my intent became clear ...

Comment: Don't forget to quote `#result`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `+ value` outside of the quotes. Also, I wouldn't build query strings manually. Just pass an object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'lookup.php',
    data: {
        s: '<?php echo $id; ?>',
        q: value
    },
    success: function(data) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of including the variable `value` your just including the string 'value', you need to move the variable outside the quotes. It should be like this:

```
$.get('lookup.php?s=<?php echo $id?>&q=' + value,function(data) {
```

Comment: Don't forget to properly encode `value` with `encodeURIComponent`.

Answer (score 0):

Your value should be outside of quotation marks:

```
$.get('lookup.php?s=<?php echo $id?>&q='+value,function(data) {
```

When the variable is placed inside of the quotation marks, it is just seen as the string "value".

Comment: Don't forget to properly encode `value` with `encodeURIComponent`.

Comment: OMG! I can´t believe it. It´s working great ! All that hours just because of wrong quotes. Thank you ! :-) This is incredible. Should have joinded stackoverflow long before ...

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('lookup.php?s=<?php echo $id?>&q='+ value,function(data) {
```

Comment: Don't forget to properly encode `value` with `encodeURIComponent`.